# Printing expressions rather than values in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to print
 `(1+2)` 
as an expression rather than its evaluation 3 in Haskell. I have tried print and show options but it is still giving 3 instead of (1+2).

Comment: There is no way to do this in vanilla Haskell, since there is no expression type.

Answer (score 8):

That's not a thing you can do with the `Prelude` types, like `Int` or `Integer`.  Haskell isn't a language that keeps expressions around at runtime.  But Haskell does make numeric literals polymorphic, and you can always create data types that do keep *some* representation of the expression around.

Or you can use a library that does all that.  [simple-reflect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect-0.3.3) is one that does that.

```
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect.Expr> 1 + 2 :: Expr
1 + 2
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect.Expr> (1 + 2) * 3 :: Expr
(1 + 2) * 3
```

Note that it works based on implementing all the numeric type class operations, not as textual analysis.  For instance, it does its own pretty-printing:

```
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect.Expr> 1 + (2 * 3) :: Expr
1 + 2 * 3
```

See how it lost the parens there?  That's because they were redundant, and it can pretty-print an identical expression without them.

Even further in this direction, operations that aren't part of the numeric type classes aren't represented in the `Expr` type, so you get things like this:

```
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect.Expr> foldl (+) 0 [1..5] :: Expr
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

The `foldl` is evaluated in its entirety, rather than kept around symbolically.  That's because `foldl` isn't an operation in any of the numeric type classes, so `Expr` can't have any instances that preserve it.

So - in general, not possible.  Haskell isn't a language that keeps representations of source expressions around at runtime.  But it *is* a language that gives you really powerful capabilities for working with new and interesting types, and depending on your needs, maybe that's good enough.